# Efficient way to concatenate multiple numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

#### Problem

I want to concatenate multiple 2-dimensional numpy arrays having shape (1, N).
As an example, let's say I want to concatenate multiple `np.array([1, 1])`.

#### My inefficient solution

A very inefficient way to do this is the following:

```
main_array = np.array([])
for i in range(0, 10):    
    if main_array.size == 0:
        # necessary step otherwise the first time the two arrays have different shapes
        main_array = np.expand_dims(np.array([1, 1]), 0)                                                          
    else:
        main_array = np.concatenate((main_array, np.expand_dims(np.array([1, 1]), 0)))
```

The result, as expected, is a numpy array having shape `(10, 2)`.

#### Question

How can I make this operation more efficient?

#### EDIT:

In my example, I add 10 times the same array for the sake of simplicity. This is probably confusing since I am actually looking for an efficient way to add *any* array and not necessarily the same one.

Comment: `np.vstack([list of arrays])`?

Comment: Do one concatenate on the whole list of arrays.  List comprehension or append is more efficient than repeated concatenates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [np.tile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html)

**Code**

```
np.tile(np.array([1, 1]), (10, 1))
# Output: Same as OP
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1]])
```

**Explanation**

Function [np.tile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html)

Usage: np.tile(A, reps)

*parameter A*

> Object which acts as a “tile” that gets copied and repeated
>
> - Numpy array
> - Python list
> - Python tuple

*parameter reps*

> Indicates how to repeat the input array if reps is an integer then A is
> repeated n times, horizontally.  If reps is a tuple (e.g. (r, c))
>
> - r is the number of repeats downwards and
> - c is the number of repeats across.

**Adding Different Arrays Vertically**

Using vstack

```
arr1 = np.array([1, 1])
arr2 = np.array([2, 2])
arr3 = np.array([3, 3])
arr = [arr1, arr2, arr3]
np.vstack(arr)

# Output
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3]])
```

Comment: Thanks, you answer my question because in my example I am adding 10 times the same array. I am actually looking for a more general way to add different arrays, not necessarily the same array. This is not clear from my question, sorry.

Comment: @maurock--extended answer to show adding different arrays.  Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Your method doesn't require the if-else statement or to increase the dimensionality, so it's much more efficient, thanks!

Comment: @maurock--glad to help.  The primary improvement is to avoid Python for loops (very slow relative to using a built-in function that does the looping in C).